# Refactoring jQuery/JavaScript code for showing/hiding a large number of modal windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many of these functions at the moment:

```
function show_foo() {
   $('.modal').hide(); // hide all modals
   $('#foo').show(); // show the foo modal
}

function show_bar() {
   $('.modal').hide();
   $('#bar').show();
}
```

The trouble is that I have about 10 of these functions and it looks clumsy.  Is there some more elegant way to do this sort of thing?

Many thanks.

Comment: Give the function a unified name and pass the ID as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace those functions with a single line, like this:

```
$('.modal').hide().filter('#bar').show();
```

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't prevent needing ten of those.

Answer (score 2):

```
function hideModalAndShow(id) {
   $('.modal').hide();
   $('#' + id).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the functions look like same, you can do something like this

```
function toggleModal(classToHide, idToShow) {
   $('.' + classToHide).hide(); // hide all modals
   $('#' + idToSHow).show(); // show the foo modal
}
```

And call this like:-

```
toggleModal('modal', 'foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hand the selector as an argument to the function.

```
function show(selector) {
   $('.modal').hide();
   $(selector).show();
}

show('#bar');
```

Now you can hand over a selector string or a jquery object.
Moving the `#` into the function is not recommended because that would be less reusable and more fragile, but that depends on your usecase.

```
show('bar');

$('#' + selector).show();
```

If the class `.modal` is subject to change, you may want to modify the function even further and hand the selector for the modal as a second (optional) parameter.

```
function show(selector,modal) {
   $(modal?modal:'.modal').hide();
   $(selector).show();
}
```

This way you *can* hand over a selector for the modal, but it will take the default if no parameter for the modal is handed over.